# Should I use validate presence in my model when I have already put the form field as required

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just a theory question,

I have already made a field in my form required, should I still use Active Record Validations presence option? (`validates *, :presence => true`)

Thanks

Comment: Entirely depends on how confident you wish to be that a field will always be present. You could always have a front-end, Rails model, and database-level validation if you wanted to be even more sure. Depends on your use case and requirements. There is no objective answer to your "should I" question since we don't know your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must add Model Level(Back-end) validation, cause sometimes, Smart people or developer can remove front-end validation by "Inspect element", at that time you can not prevent him/her by living blank values in textbox.
In this type of scenario only Back-end validation prevent users from filling blank data.

```
    validates :column_name, presence: true
```